# Excel VBA - Save checked checkboxes to cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with several checkboxes. I want to save the ticked checkboxes in different sequential rows of the same column.

For example, if I selected 5 checkboxes then I want to save them in cell(4,9), cell(5,9), etc. I have the code almost done, but I'm having trouble writing a while loop that will make it go from cell(4,9) to cell(5,9) and etc.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub seg_b_next2_Click()

Dim indProdWs As Worksheet
Set indProdWs = tWb.Worksheets("INDICATION-PRODUCT")

Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
        If ctl.Value = True Then
            i = 0
            While whatever_happens
            indProdWs.Range(4 + i, 9) = ctl.Caption
            i = i + 1
            Wend
        End If
    End If
Next ctl

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, please:

```
Private Sub seg_b_next2_Click()
 Dim indProdWs As Worksheet, ctl As Control, i As Long
 
 Set indProdWs = Twb.Worksheets("INDICATION-PRODUCT")

 i = 4
 For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
        If ctl.Value = True Then
            indProdWs.Range(i, 9).Value = ctl.Caption: i = i + 1
        End If
    End If
 Next ctl
End Sub
```

Comment: You're a genius! Can you please explain me how this part ctl.Caption: i = i + 1 works?

Comment: @soraia635: Very simple: When first caption has been copied to the cell, the `i` variable value has been incremented by 1. Next time it will be 5, 6 and so on...